# which record types can see a picklist value?

Tags: apex, record-type

Aside from going through each record type through the UI and clicking over to the field to see if a RT can see a picklist value is there  a faster way? maybe by using the .object file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picklist values can be edited directly in the object file. Within the recordTypes XML node, use the following syntax:

```
  <recordTypes>
    <fullName>Partner</fullName>
    <active>true</active>
    <description>For all partners</description>
    <label>Partner</label>
    <picklistValues>
        <picklist>Accept_Donations__c</picklist>
        <values>
            <fullName>No</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Requested</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
        <values>
            <fullName>Yes</fullName>
            <default>false</default>
        </values>
    </picklistValues>
```

Comment: That's editing- not searching.... with what you showed me, i wouldn't be able to do a regular expression on that